# Where are all the questions going?

Tags: bug

No.  Not those questions.

[image: scifi meta]

[image: arqade]

The white blobs should say "Questions".

The don't reappear after refresh and aren't consistently missing between sites. Navigating around fixes the issues.

I'm tempted to [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com) but I thought I'd flag this up anyway.